# Create c# app setup with database project

Tags: c#, wpf, installation, localdb

So basically I want to have an installer for my WPF application. In the setup process I want to automatically create a localdb. For this I already have a database project in the solution that contains all the tables for my database.
I was already able to manage to have an installer for the application itself. For this I used the "*Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects*" addon in VS 2015. My questions:

1. How can I automatically create a localdb instance in the setup process?
2. How can I use the database project to automatically create the database?
3. Is there a better solution to create setup file, than the mentioned?

Comment: Perhaps look at using Powershell to run the SQL script(s) during the installation.

Comment: Sort of a solution, but still not using the data base project. So for this I have to generate the sql script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the .dacpac file in the Database project, include the dacpac in the WPF app as embedded resource, and use the DacFX SDK to install/update the database based on a connection string.

Code sample: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/blob/issue-357-a/src/GUI/SqlCe35Toolbox/Helpers/DacFxHelper.cs

DacFX is available as a NuGet package now:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64/
or
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x86/

Comment: Seems promissing, but I can't release the database with the installer in this way. (Okay if i create a consol application and attach exe, it could work, but not really a nice way to solve this issue)